# Patch alpha channel does not work with "copy figure"?

Tags: matlab, patch

I want to copy the figure, keeping the vector based graphics. The reason for this is that I want to use the figure in Powerpoint. I cannot save the figure in .eps format, since Powerpoint will format the plot to some TIFF format or so and will only use the vector format, when printing on paper.

However, there is a workaround. If I use the "copy figure" option under the "edit" menu, Matlab will copy the figure in vector format and then I will get a better resolution in Powerpoint. This is probably because Powerpoint will read it as some object and not as a image.

My problem arises when I want to plot something with a semi-transparent background made by patch. The problem is that the "copy figure" option ignores the alpha channel, which once again makes my background opaque. Is there any way to copy the figure, but read the alpha channel as well?

My guess is that the figure is exported as 24-bits, how could I verify/change that?

Here is some code that can be used for testing:

```
v = exp(1i*[pi/4,3*pi/4,5*pi/4,7*pi/4,pi/4]+1i*pi/8);
figure(2); patch(real(v),imag(v),[0,0.9,0.1],'FaceAlpha',0.1)
axis off
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It seems you can use the print command to export to e.g. an EPS file:

```
print -depsc fig1.eps
```

More info here:
http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html

Comment: Please add the info here! :)\